# How to delete a Worker and a plugin on AWS MSK Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

Can't find a way to delete a worker configuration and a custom plugin
in Amazon MSK service UI.

[image: Amazon MSK]

Comment: This is a better question for AWS MSK support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In today's date (29/12/2021) there is no option to delete it.

Here is the CLI reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kafkaconnect/index.html#cli-aws-kafkaconnect

Comment: That's surprising.

Comment: My recommendation, don't use MSK Connect. Its not mature enough. You have to pass secrets in plain text.

Comment: At least now you can pass secrets through a config provider, for example, using AWS Secrets Manager